# Handling of SQL exception in spring integration flow

Tags: spring-integration

In my spring service , I am taking input from a queue. After receiving data from queue , we are trying to fetch some data from the input XML , and trying to insert that data in DB .

I am not able to figure out , is there any way to handle the DB operation failure. Is there any way by which I can put my input XML back to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

You `queue` has to be `<queue>` channel with persistence `MessageStore` and `<poller>` for that `queue` has to be `<transactional>`.

In this case the expception in the downstream flow initiates a TX rollback and your message will ramain in the `queue`.